# Align Bullet and Content in the middle

Tags: html, css

I was to align the bullet and the content (email Us) to the center (shown in the picture below). How do I do it in CSS?

[image]

```css
.columbia-article-topic-category .mt-listing-detailed-subpages .mt-listing-article-list .mt-show-more-listing [class*='mt-icon-article'] {
  margin: auto .4em auto 0;
}

.columbia-article-topic-category .mt-listing-detailed-subpages .mt-listing-article-list .mt-show-more-listing [class*='mt-icon-article']:before {
  display: block;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: .6em;
  width: .6em;
  align-content: center;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at .33em .33em, #00f3ff, #000);
  content: ' ';
}
```

```html
<dt class="mt-listing-detailed-title"><a title="SUGGESTION BOX" class="internal" href="https://documentationcenter.alip.accenture.com/SUGGESTION_BOX" rel="internal"><span class="mt-icon-article-topic-category"></span>SUGGESTION BOX</a></dt>

<dd class="mt-listing-detailed-subpages">
  <ul class="mt-listings-simple mt-listing-article-list mt-topic-hierarchy-listings mt-guide-listings mt-reveal-listing">
    <li class="mt-show-more-listing"><a title="Email Us" class="mt-listing-detailed-subpage-title internal" href="https://documentationcenter.alip.accenture.com/SUGGESTION_BOX/Email_Us" rel="internal"><span class="mt-icon-article-topic-guide"></span>Email Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</dd>
```

Here is the [link to the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ag41ok2c/) with the code.

> I have limited CSS and coding knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I have made few changes in css. Please have look.

```css
.mt-show-more-listing, .mt-listing-detailed-title{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="mt-listing-detailed-title">
  <a title="SUGGESTION BOX" class="internal" href="https://documentationcenter.alip.accenture.com/SUGGESTION_BOX" rel="internal">SUGGESTION BOX</a>
</div>


<ul class="mt-listings-simple mt-listing-article-list mt-topic-hierarchy-listings mt-guide-listings mt-reveal-listing">
  <li class="mt-show-more-listing"><a title="Email Us" class="mt-listing-detailed-subpage-title internal" href="https://documentationcenter.alip.accenture.com/SUGGESTION_BOX/Email_Us" rel="internal">Email Us</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is just aligning the text and not the bullets

Comment: @PankajMorajkar please check it now

Comment: Sorry I dont understand...you removed the CSS, is it?

Comment: I realized that by changing the margin from .4em to 4em brings the content to the middle. can you check how i can make the bullets besides the content          .columbia-article-topic-category .mt-listing-detailed-subpages .mt-listing-article-list .mt-show-more-listing [class*='mt-icon-article']{
       margin:auto 4em auto 0;

}

Answer (score 0):

Add some `css`

```
    .mt-listing-detailed-subpages {
      margin-left: 0;
      text-align: center;
     }
    .mt-listings-simple {
      padding-left: 0px;
    }
```

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ronn8m0y/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Added a class center and wrapped your html in a div using the class.

```css
.columbia-article-topic-category .mt-listing-detailed-subpages .mt-listing-article-list .mt-show-more-listing [class*='mt-icon-article']{
       margin:auto .4em auto 0;

}

.columbia-article-topic-category .mt-listing-detailed-subpages .mt-listing-article-list .mt-show-more-listing [class*='mt-icon-article']:before{
  display: block;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: .6em;
  width: .6em;
  align-content: center;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at .33em .33em, #00f3ff, #000);
  content:' ';
}
.center{
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:left;
}
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">

<dt class="mt-listing-detailed-title"><a title="SUGGESTION BOX" class="internal" href="https://documentationcenter.alip.accenture.com/SUGGESTION_BOX" rel="internal"><span class="mt-icon-article-topic-category"></span>SUGGESTION BOX</a></dt>

<dd class="mt-listing-detailed-subpages"><ul class="mt-listings-simple mt-listing-article-list mt-topic-hierarchy-listings mt-guide-listings mt-reveal-listing"><li class="mt-show-more-listing"><a title="Email Us" class="mt-listing-detailed-subpage-title internal" href="https://documentationcenter.alip.accenture.com/SUGGESTION_BOX/Email_Us" rel="internal"><span class="mt-icon-article-topic-guide"></span>Email Us</a></li></ul></dd>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the update code

```css
.columbia-article-topic-category .mt-listing-detailed-subpages .mt-listing-article-list .mt-show-more-listing [class*='mt-icon-article']{
       margin:auto .4em auto 0;

}

.columbia-article-topic-category .mt-listing-detailed-subpages .mt-listing-article-list .mt-show-more-listing [class*='mt-icon-article']:before{
  display: block;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: .6em;
  width: .6em;
  align-content: center;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at .33em .33em, #00f3ff, #000);
  content:' ';
}

.mt-listing-detailed-title {
  text-align: center;
}
.mt-listing-detailed-subpages {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<dt class="mt-listing-detailed-title"><a title="SUGGESTION BOX" class="internal" href="https://documentationcenter.alip.accenture.com/SUGGESTION_BOX" rel="internal"><span class="mt-icon-article-topic-category"></span>SUGGESTION BOX</a></dt>

<dd class="mt-listing-detailed-subpages"><ul class="mt-listings-simple mt-listing-article-list mt-topic-hierarchy-listings mt-guide-listings mt-reveal-listing"><li class="mt-show-more-listing"><a title="Email Us" class="mt-listing-detailed-subpage-title internal" href="https://documentationcenter.alip.accenture.com/SUGGESTION_BOX/Email_Us" rel="internal"><span class="mt-icon-article-topic-guide"></span>Email Us</a></li></ul></dd>
```

Comment: I realized that by changing the margin from .4em to 4em brings the content to the middle. can you check how i can make the bullets besides the content .columbia-article-topic-category .mt-listing-detailed-subpages .mt-listing-article-list .mt-show-more-listing [class*='mt-icon-article']{ margin:auto 4em auto 0; } –

Answer (score -1):

width: //allow some with here ;
margin: auto;